# Exchanging NServiceBus messages with native implementation of Azure Service Bus

Tags: c#, nservicebus, azureservicebus

Consuming a message published with NServiceBus, using IQueueClient/Functions-ServiceBusTrigger (Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus)

I'm working in a WebJob using .NET Core and Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus to consume a message that has been published by a separate service using NServiceBus. My initial approach with this WebJob was to use a class `Functions.cs` with a method `ProcessMessage` that uses the attribute `ServiceBusTrigger`

Below is an example of how my `Function.cs` looks like:

```
public class Functions
{
   public Task ProcessAuditLogMessage([ServiceBusTrigger("MyQueue")] 
      Message message)
   {
      var messageBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body);
      var auditLogMessage = JsonConvert
            .DeserializeObject<MyMessage>(messageBody);

      _logger.Information("Hello World");

      return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

In `Program.cs`, I have:

```
class Program
{
   static async Task Main()
   {
      var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
      serviceCollection.AddWebJobs(o => o.AllowPartialHostStartup = true);

      var builder = new HostBuilder()
         .UseServiceProviderFactory(
              new AutofacServiceProviderFactory(serviceCollection))
         .ConfigureContainer<ContainerBuilder>(b =>
         {
            BuildAutofacContainer();
         })
         .ConfigureWebJobs(b =>
         {
            b.AddServiceBus(o =>
            {
               o.ConnectionString = configProvider.AuditLogServiceBus;
             });
          });

      var host = builder.Build();

      using (host)
      {
         await host.RunAsync();
      }
   }

   private static IContainer BuildAutofacContainer(IServiceColletion 
          serviceCollection)
   {
      ...
   }
}
```

I was expecting that this logic would consume the messages published in the Queue but so far the messages get moved to the Dead-letter count with a `DeadLetterReason`: `MaxDeliveryCountExceeded` and the error description `Message could not be consumed after 10 delivery attempts` which gives me the indication that at least there is an attempt to get these messages delivered to my consumer.

Unfortunately that's all I have in terms of error messages/logs (I'm in the process to set up some logs from my Azure Dashboard and see if I can get more detailed logs)

Has anyone come across the scenario o having to consume messages, that have been published with NServiceBus, using Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus instead of NServiceBus (on the consumer side). Maybe I'm missing something...

Comment: If message is sent from NServiceBus endpoint and serialized using JSON, it should work. Try logging exception thrown during function execution. Perhaps Function expects to see content type that is not set by NServiceBus, similar to what was recently fixed in the new ASB transport https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus.Transport.AzureServiceBus/pull/47

Comment: @SeanFeldman I'm using Newtonsoft Serialization. I have also tried to use the service bus connection string in `Functions.ProcessAuditLogMessage` e.g. `ProcessAuditLogMessage([ServiceBusTrigger("MyQueue", connectionString)] Message message)` but then my Service Bus does not even try to deliver the message to my consumer

Comment: Newtonsoft Serialization serializes message as JSON. Would be really helpful if you could do `try/catch` and log the exception in your Function to understand what the issue is. If `MaxDeliveryCount` count is exceeded, the Function receives the message, but fails to process. The only processing I see in your code is deserialization.

Comment: @SeanFeldman, The main problem is that the processing method in my `Function.cs` doesn't get hit so even if I try to catch any exception there, that code will never be reached. I ended up creating a separate class where I register a message handler into a QueueClient and call this message pump in `Program.cs` through my Autofac container. This time my consumer is getting the messages from Service Bus. However, it would be good to know how a Function works with the new generic host in .NET Core.

Comment: You might be having BOM / Encoding issues

https://jimmybogard.com/the-curious-case-of-the-json-bom/

Are you using the latest NServiceBus.NewtonSoft package for your NServiceBus version that contains https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus.Newtonsoft.Json/pull/54?